# Return type for all implementations of a Protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a little Problem. I need to specify a return value for a function that can return every implementation of a Protocol. For Example:

My Protocol:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    //some functions
}
```

Implementations:

```
class ClassA: MyProtocol {
}

class ClassB: MyProtocol {
}
```

The "problem" function:

```
func getClassByString(_ name: String) -> MyProtocol.Type {
    switch name {
    case "a":
        return ClassA.self
    case "b":
        return ClassB.self
    default:
        return ClassC.self
    }
}
```

**//EDIT:** This is where i need the result

```
final class Mapper<N: MyProtocol> {
    public func map() -> N?{
        if let klass = N.self as? MyProtocol.Type {
            return klass as? N
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let className = "a" //this String comes from a JSON
let result = getClassByString(className)

let mappingResult = Mapper<result>().map() //undeclared identifier 'result' error
let mappingResult = Mapper<ClassA>().map() //works but i do not know if it is ClassA
```

The Problem is that `result` isn't really `ClassA.Type`, what it should be, it is now `MyProtocol.Type` and I can't pass this to the next Function.
When I give `result` the specific value of `ClassA.self` everything works. I can't cast it to `as! ClassA.self` because i do not know if ist has to be `ClassA` or `ClassB` or `Class9000`

So the question is. Is there another return type like `MyProtocol.Type` for the function `getClassByString()` or a completely different way to get `ClassA.Type` to `result` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem here is not exactly as you describe - the `result` of your example actually does appear to be a `ClassA.Type` in Playground, but the problem I suspect is what you do with it next. Your protocol does not say *how* such types are to be instantiated in a generic fashion, so the type returned cannot *be* instantiated.

I've made a few changes to your example, and it now works ...

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    //some functions
    init() // To instantiate generically, there MUST be an accepted pattern for init()
}

class ClassA: MyProtocol {
    required init() {}
}    
class ClassB: MyProtocol {
    required init() {}
}
class ClassC: MyProtocol {
    required init() {}
}

func getClassByString(_ name: String) -> MyProtocol.Type {
    switch name {
    case "a":
        return ClassA.self
    case "b":
        return ClassB.self
    default:
        return ClassC.self
    }
}

let className = "a" //this String comes from a JSON
let result = getClassByString(className) // ClassA.Type
let a = result.init() // ClassA
```

Comment: Note that although `type(of: a)` will report `ClassA`, we may not call e.g. an instance method of `ClassA` which is not blueprinted in `MyProtocol` on `a`. Say `ClassA` has a method `foo() -> ()`, then `a.foo()` will yield the error message _"error: value of type `MyProtocol` has no member `foo`"_. But I guess this is expected or the static typing of Swift would fail in this case (undetermined at compile time).

Comment: @dfri - That's exactly my point - to call `init()` it A) has to be specified in the protocol and B) has to be `required` in the implementation...

Comment: Indeed, I'm pointing this out explicitly (mainly for OP) as I believe OP is trying to solve an XY problem, using methods that are not suitable for a statically typed language as Swift. In the end, OP will only be able to work with the `MyProtocol` layered type, as we can never know at compile time the concrete type of `a`, which has led the OP to reason over appraoches as `(a as! ClassA).foo()`. I speculate that proceeding in this direction will lead to code smells reasoning for the OP, and he/she might want to re-visit the original problem before proceeding with attempted "runtime typing".

Comment: (... might be worth mentioning that even if we instantiate `a` "generically" (by `init` available from blueprint) above, this is not the end of it: `a` is still not a concrete `ClassA`, which might be misunderstood from the final code snippet in the answer above, in case one is not familiar with the statically typed essence of Swift).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited my question to make it clearer what I need `result` for.

Comment: @dfri - move your (correct and useful) comments to the OQ - I'm going to delete my answer as it is no longer an answer to the edited question...

Comment: I believe your answer is still useful in combination with our discussion below: the core being that the OP will have to work with the `MyProtocol` layered type as the concrete type cannot be known at compile time. I did begin to move my comments but realized they kind of lost their value when not attached to this answer, so delete it if you'd like, but imo it brings value here :)

Comment: @dfri - So the final answer is "It's not possible because of compiler." ? In this case you can post it as an answer that i have to deal with ;)

Comment: @ChiefLutz - on the contrary - it's perfectly possible if you specify how the protocol constructs the instances... but impossible if you do not, as the compiler cannot guess what the constructors are!

Comment: but even when I specify constructors like in your answer, I'm not able to put the instances in the `Mapper<>`. Like @dfri said in a comment "the concrete type cannot be known at compile time"

Comment: Indeed, but you have no need to do that, as you can instantiate them directly when needed.

Comment: Yes I understand that i can use this to instantiate them and this really works perfect but it isn't solving my Problem. I do not need the instances at all. I just have to find a way to put them in the generic class. This is the Mapper from the ObjectMapper Framework.

Comment: @dfri - Grimxn, So no additions to this? Then I think there is no way to do this what i wanted to do. Have to find another way. Thank you guys.